# Matching strings across non-consecutive rows with AWK

Tags: regex, awk

I have been working with an AWK one-liner that does a good job of identifying string matches on previous rows, i.e. comparing field x on row n with field y on row (n+1). E.g., say input file consists of rows, 3 fields each:

```
A B C
B B B
C C C
D B D
```

The one-liner is:

```
awk "$2==a[2] { print a[1],a[2],a[3] } { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i }"
```

So this example prints out all three fields of any **immediately previous row** that matches on field 2, which in this case is only row 1. So the output would be:

```
A B C
```

Now, I'm wondering if there is a modification to this command that will allow me to find matches between the current row and the row that is **2 rows before it**, or **3 rows before it**, or even 4 rows before it.
So using the same sample input file, if I was trying to make matches for "2 rows before", on field 2, it would now only output

```
B B B
```

which is row 2, because it is the only instance of the 2nd field ("B") matching with the second field in the row that is 2 rows ahead (i.e. row 4).
I'm not terribly familiar with arrays. I'm guessing the run time will suffer but is the original command modifiable in this way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this awk:

```
awk 'a[FNR%n,m]==$m {print a[FNR%n]}{a[FNR%n]=$0; a[FNR%n,m]=$m}' n=2 m=3 file.txt
```

The above will print the *n<sup>th</sup>* line, before the current line if field *m* in both lines match.

The above will keep the memory nicely in check: if you don't care too much about memory consumption, you can do this:

```
awk '(FNR-n,$m) in a {print a[FNR-n,$m]}{a[FNR,$m]=$0}' n=2 m=3 file.txt
```

Comment: The 1st one works well. And if there was the added complexity of matching current line field m with nth previous line field x ? In other words, m and x columns instead of m column common to both rows being matched ?

Comment: The following awk does the check of field `m2` of the current line with field `m1` of the line `n` lines ago: `awk 'a[FNR%n,m1]==$m2 {print a[FNR%n]}{a[FNR%n]=$0; a[FNR%n,m1]=$m1}' n=2 m1=3 m2=2 file.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```
cat prev.awk
FNR > p && n = split(row[FNR-p], cols) && $2 == cols[2] {
   print row[FNR-p]
}
{
   row[FNR] = $0
}
```

Then use it for current-2 row matching:

```
awk -v p=2 -f prev.awk file
```

```
B B B
```

and current-1 row matching:

```
awk -v p=1 -f prev.awk file
```

```
A B C
```

Comment: That works anubhava but I I'm flying blind with it and was unable to successfully modify the matching conditions. At the moment, in my example and yours, the match is on column 2 in both rows ("$2 == cols[2]") so I assumed the first term was current row and the second one ("cols[2]") was the n-2 row, but it didn't work when I started playing around with it. Is there somewhere else that the matching conditions need to be changed ?

Comment: Actually `cols` is an array that is generated by calling `split` function on `current - p`th row. So if `p=2` then `$2 == cols[2]` compared current 2nd column with 2nd column of (current-2)th row.

Comment: Yes I know that. My point is that if I change it to, say, $2 -- cols[3] I would have thought it would then find a match between current 2nd column and 3rd column of (current-2) row. But it doesn't.

Comment: If p=2, then A B C

Comment: It will also print `B B B` because 3rd col is `B` which is same as 2nd col in 4th row.

Comment: Oh yes. But it prints neither

Comment: Check this demo: https://ideone.com/VmmSLa It prints `A B C` and `B B B` as I said.

Comment: May be your input file has DOS line ending. You can either run `dos2unix` beforehand or use `awk -v RS='\r?\n' -v p=2 -f prev.awk file`

Comment: Yes - DOS line ending was the problem. Well done, good solution